# Where can I launchs VMs with size B1S?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure account that gives me free access to certain types of resources for a year. Each month, I have the right to launch 750 hours worth of virtual machines of size B1S.

Now, I have tried several regions (US East, US South, Japan East, Japan West), and B1S is not listed in any of them. The list invariably starts with B2S.

**Which regions offer B1S?**

Answer (score 1):

The B1s size is available in your regions. You can check it with the following command in azure cli:

```
az vm list-sizes --location "eastus" | Select-String B1S
```

output:

```
"name": "Standard_B1s",
```

I think the reason for your question is because by default the B1S size isn't in the dropdownlist inside the GUI of the vm creation menu. Below the Dropdown-List for "Size", there is a field "Change Size". You to click on it and then you can select B1S in another menu:
[image]

Resource: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal

Furthermore, you can also create a vm with the azure cli and your preferred size, after you created a resource group:

#Create resource group

```
az group create -l eastus -n MyResourceGroup
```

#Create B1S VM

```
az vm create \
    --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
    --name myB1SVM \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --size Standard_B1s \
    --generate-ssh-keys
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation, Lukas. I just noticed as well that this size does exist. I am sorry for not asking the correct question. In fact, I wanted to create Azure Kubernetes Service workers with size B1s, and **that** is not possible, it seems. My guess is that the memory size is deemed to small.